# the asynctask function is not recognizing the result value

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I am accessing via AsyncTask the JSON, but in the onPostExecute, the String result is not getting the result value.

I would like it to read json and return the value "perfil", after that, send new to the main activity

credits Google Translate....

Acess MainActivity to MecanismoString

```
String login = textousuario.getText().toString();
            String senha = textosenha.getText().toString();
            String urllogin = "http...."
            String tipo = "";
            MecanismoString mecanismoString = new MecanismoString(this, this);
            mecanismoString.execute(tipo, urllogin, login, senha);
```

Asynctask MecanismoString

```
public class MecanismoString extends AsyncTask <String, String, String> {

    private Interfacestring Interfacestring;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private StringRequest request;
    private Interfacestring execinterface;

    String usuario, senha, result;

    Context context;
    Toast toast;

    public MecanismoString (Context context, Interfacestring execinterface){
        this.context = context;
        this.Interfacestring = execinterface;
    }




    @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... params) {

        Log.i("Script", "1 ->" + params[0]);
        Log.i("Script", "2 ->" + params[1]);
        Log.i("Script", "3 ->" + params[2]);
        Log.i("Script", "4 ->" + params[3]);

        usuario = params[2];
        senha = params[3];

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, params[1], new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                    result = jsonObject.getString("perfil");


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hashMap.put("login", usuario);
                hashMap.put("senha", senha);

                return hashMap;
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(request);

        return (result);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        execinterface.carregarString(result);

    }

}
```

code that returns the value of MecanismoString

```
public void carregarString(String result) {

        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),
                result,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();

    }
```

Error Log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ic.eng.br.eunaobra, PID: 13735
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void ic.eng.br.eunaobra.Interfacestring.carregarString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at ic.eng.br.eunaobra.MecanismoString.onPostExecute(MecanismoString.java:94)
        at ic.eng.br.eunaobra.MecanismoString.onPostExecute(MecanismoString.java:22)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
    (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 76 failed errno=-22
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: untagSocket(76) failed with errno -22
Application terminated.
```

Comment: in MecanismoString  constructor i think you are not referecning the interface correctly

Comment: try this
public MecanismoString (Context context, Interfacestring execinterface){
        this.context = context;
        this.execinterface= execinterface;
    }

Comment: was a bug too, duplicate interface, but continues with this error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

please pass a correct context and execinterface object :

```
MecanismoString mecanismoString = new MecanismoString(MainActivity.this, correct execinterface object);
```

please remove `getApplicationContext()` from `carregarString()`since you already have a `context`:

```
 public void carregarString(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(context,result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();
    }
```

Comment: of the error when declared object instead of "this", changed the "Toast", but the error persists: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference at android.widget.Toast.<init>

Comment: sorry , i can't understand what you just wrote , could you pleas be more explicit ?

Comment: n summary, I need the result value, which is inside of the InBackground to be received in onPostExecute, but I'm doing something wrong ...
I am not able to send the String result to onPostExecute

Comment: could you do return result instead of (result) ? and also make a break point at line return to see if the result is well generated

Comment: I found the error, I dismounted the whole process. I was on toast. ` toast = Toast.makeText(this, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();` now I'm reinserion the JSON

Comment: great , so hope my answer and intervention were helpful

Comment: if you look at my code, I'm getting the result as follows: ```result = jsonObject.getString("perfil");``` the ```result return;``` is empty, how do I get the result ```result = jsonObject.getString("perfil");```

Comment: could you post the jsonObject then i can expect it

Comment: the jsonObject you get in your onResponse() in doInbackground

Comment: ```protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject obj){
            if(obj != null)
            {}}``` like this?

Comment: did you understand my question ? i asked you for the value of the jsonObject you receive ,

Comment: is receiving an integer, in this case the value 1

Comment: So how could you receive an integer with getString ?

Comment: sorry, I'm going to load several strings, I am testing with this to understand the mechanism, but since this is a login only screen and will only receive the value String = 1; to direct to the Activity